# Переадресация с включением содержимого input

Tags: javascript, redirect

есть site.com с поиском. при поиске редиректит на страницу site.com/search/node/ваш_запрос (друпал)

Есть HTML страничка на поддомене, типа test.site.com
на ней Input и Button

Как мне сделать, чтобы при вбивании (к примеру) поискового запроса "тест" в форму в поддомене test.site.com и нажатии на кнопку меня перекидывало на основной домен site.com/search/node/тест (имитация поиска на поддомене)
в джаваскрипте я ноль почти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зайдите на ваш основной сайт, и посмотрите код формы поиска в инспекторе объектов (правой кнопкой мыши на форме - пункт "показать код" - в появившемся в инспекторе дереве DOM найти тег `form`).

- В теге `form` вы увидите атрибут `action` с путем до корректного роута поиска. Например, до `/search/node`
- В теге `input` внутри формы вы увидите атрибут `name` с корректным названием поля текста для поиска. Например, `search_query`

Теперь на вашем поддомене - просто постройте такую же форму с таким же полем:

```
<form id="search" action="//site.com/search/node" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="search_query"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

> Обратите внимание на `method="get"` у формы - поисковые формы обычно отсылают данные на сервер GET-запросом, но, возможно, в вашем случае форма шлется методом POST - посмотрите, как это сделано в форме на основном домене и сделайте так же.
>
> Также у кнопки может быть `type="submit"`, а может быть `type="search"`, тоже сделайте как в основной форме.

В итоге - вы получите рабочую форму для поиска, перебрасывающую вас с поддомена на основной домен, без javascript.